# sed cannot find special string such as </Engine> tag

Tags: xml, sed, tags

I have spent hours searching how to insert text above a specific line containing the only string tag `</Engine>` in railo tomcat server.xml file.

I have tried to escape with

```
sed -nr '/\<\/Engine\>/p' /opt/railo/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

to find what line number this string is, but I always receive error messages.

My goal is to automatically insert the new host name information when I create a new user above the closing `</Engine>` tag as it will make it easier to maintain.

I am not good with text/string manipulation and I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: provide an example along with expected output.

Comment: Don't use sed for this. Use something that understands xml. Like `xsltproc` or `xmlstarlet` or a programming languages xml support.

Comment: My apologies for answering..I see you found your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question.

`sed -n '/<\/Engine>/ ='` gives me the correct line number. So I can use this pattern in my script now.

Answer (score 0):

This command below will match all lines with with `</Engine>` only and put a line of text above it

```
sed '\#^</Engine>$#i\<put_your_text_here>'
```

`<put_your_text_here>` is the text you will put above this line

Note also I used  "#" as sed's delimiter since your string has `/` to avoid conflict

EDIT

if the tag have spaces before and after it **or no spaces** you can try

```
sed '\#^[ ]*</Engine>[ ]*$#i\<put_your_text_here>'
```